# How to save mesh in .msh ASCII 2 format from Gmsh Python api?

Tags: python, api, mesh, fenics, gmsh

I need to save my mesh (created with gmsh python api) in `.msh` ASCII version 2 format in order to use the command dolfin-convert and import the mesh inside Fenics.

From the tutorials, to save the mesh I should use the command:

```
gmsh.write("filename.msh")
```

however, if i try to convert the mesh in .xml file (in order to use it in fenics) with the command:

```
dolfin-convert filenam.msh filename.xml
```

it returns an error:

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 25240 1 25240\n'
```

If I save manually the mesh in `.msh` ASCII 2 format everything works well.

I need an automated process so I can't save it manually every time, how can i use the Python `api` to save the mesh in the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gmsh.option.setNumber("Mesh.MshFileVersion",2.2)   
gmsh.write("filename.msh")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just a question: why version 2.2 and not simply 2? I mean, when i use the Gmsh gui i select ASCII version 2, is there a difference?

Comment: No there should not be a difference. If you save it in the GUI as version 2 it will save it as version 2.2. You can just try an save a mesh with the GUI as version 2 (ascii, not binary), and then open the .msh file with a text editor. In the second line in the file there will be the file version.